# Need help understanding $a^x$ defined as a limit

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I'm doing a big fat calculus review, going through Paul Garrett's [Calculus Refresher](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/calculus/first_year/notes.pdf). So far it's very clear and concise, but I just got stuck at one point. He lays out a bit of review on exponents (what they define, how they combine, etc.), and then says:

> $$a^{m/n} = \left(\sqrt[n]{a}\right)^{m}$$ One hazard is that, if we
>   want to have only real numbers (as opposed to complex numbers) come
>   up, then we should not try to take square roots, $4^{th}$ roots,
>   $6^{th}$ roots, or any even order root of negative numbers.

Understood. No surprises there.

> For general real exponents $x$ we likewise should not try to
>   understand $a^x$ except for $a > 0$ or we’ll have to use complex
>   numbers (which wouldn’t be so terrible). But the value of $a^x$ can
>   only be defined as a limit: let $r_1, r_2, . . .$ be a sequence of
>   rational numbers approaching $x$, and define
>   $$a^x = \lim_{i}a^{r_i}$$
>   We would have to check that this definition does not
>   accidentally depend upon the sequence approaching $x$ (it doesn’t),
>   and that the same properties still work (they do).

...And with that, I'm lost. I *think* he's saying, first, that we'd be forced out of the comfort zone of real numbers if $a^x<0$ since we could end up with something like $-4^{1/2}$. But why can the value of $a^x$ only be defined as a limit? That part, and the sequence approaching $x$ just left me in the dust. Can anyone clarify this a bit? Thanks in advance!

*very delayed update:* As was pointed out in the comments below, it seems the limit comes into play if we want to define $a^x$ for all real values of $x$, *including* irrationals. This makes a lot more sense now. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, $a^n$ (where $n$ is an integer) is defined as repeated multiplication.  The $n$-th root, or $a^{1/n}$, is defined by the inverse of this, and then all rational powers follow through $(a^{x})^{y}=a^{xy}$.  But how do you define $a^{x}$ for arbitrary irrational $x$, except by imposing continuity?

Comment: Presumably some subscripts are missing and "let $r,r,\dots$ be a sequence" ought to be "let $r_1,r_2,\dots$ be a sequence".

Comment: @mjqxxxx - I think I see what you're saying. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would suggest rephrasing the title, as it does not describe the question. Also, @mjqxxxx - why not write that as an answer?

Comment: @mjqxxxx, I think you nailed it. Thanks! I've been doing some algebra review lately, and just revisited this. Of course, it makes perfect sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

If $ a > 0 $, then an easier way of defining $ a^{x} $ for any given $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ is
$$
a^{x} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \exp(x \ln(a)).
$$
As $ \exp $ is a continuous function on $ \mathbb{R} $, we have
$$
\lim_{y \to x} \exp(y \ln(a)) = \exp \left( \lim_{y \to x} y \ln(a) \right) = \exp(x \ln(a)),
$$
which implies that
$$
\lim_{y \to x} a^{y} = a^{x}.
$$
Therefore, we can also define $ a^{x} $ as the limit of the sequence $ (a^{q_{n}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $, where $ (q_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is any sequence in $ \mathbb{Q} $ that converges to $ x $.